# how do I grab fields from json

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is what it is displayed with {{ todo }} , but whenever I try to do {{ todo.title }} nothing is displayed, how do I only grab a title and completed_at? In data, todos are []

```
[ { "id": "b8fc8820-2bdd-43e1-a05a-c4a483e44faf", "title": "TEST", "description": null, "deadline_at": null, "completed": true, "completed_at": "2020-09-16T15:21:36+02:00", "priority": false, "inserted_at": "2020-09-16T15:21:18+02:00", "updated_at": "2020-09-16T15:21:36+02:00" } ]
```

```
.col-lg-12(v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id")
        p {{ todo }}
```

Comment: `todo.title` should work assuming `todo` represents the object and not the outer array as @jeremy said

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `todo` is also an `array` so if you want to access title:

```
todo[0].title
```